# Хостинг для Android приложения

Tags: java, android, hosting

Необходим бесплатный хостинг для апробации сервера на Java. Так же необходима поддержка SQLite или другой БД. Есть ли такие хостинги?

Comment: А почему бы не пробовать не собственном компьютере? С любой БД.